# creating id for each observation in panel data

Tags: r

I have a data set with person names but I think the id is misrepresented (the ids are not unique per person right now in the data set). I would like to create a new id vector, but I was wondering how. For instance if we have the following list of names:

```
name
John
John
John
Tom
Tom
David
David
Sonia
Sonia
Ben
```

How can we create unique id per person?

```
id name
1  John
1  John
1  John
2  Tom
2  Tom
3  David
3  David
4  Sonia
4  Sonia
5  Ben
```

Seems like a simple process, but I'm not sure how I can use the loop! Any suggestions will help.

I came up with a for loop that looks close but with error:

```
> for (i in 1:5){
+   a<-unique(dat$name)
+   a<-as.vector(a)
+   dat$id[a[i]]<-i
+   dat$id[a[i+1]]<-i+1
+ }
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "id", value = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  : 
  replacement has 11 rows, data has 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also figured out the for loop

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "name
John
John
John
Tom
Tom
David
David
Sonia
Sonia
Ben" )

for (i in 1:5){
  a<-unique(dat$name)
  a<-as.vector(a)
  dat$id[dat$name==a[i]]<-i
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this , it may help

```
dat$id <- as.numeric(as.factor(dat$name))
```

where "id" is your new column and "name" is your name column, dat is original data frame